# Handling Errors From HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse

Tags: oop

I have a class called *Hotmail* that contains various method such as login, logout etc.

To illustrate the confusion I'm having I have a login method that logs the user into Hotmail via my software. The login method returns a HttpWebResponse object. But, within the login method any number of things could happen such as wrong credentials being entered or a timeout.

I'm in some confusion about how, and where to handle such errors.

In the case of the wrong credentials being entered, or a timeout, it would be pointless, or sometimes not possible to return a HttpWebResponse object. What would be the best way to handle such errors?

Should I create custom Exceptions so the code that's calling the method can check for such errors and handle them?

What's the conventional way to handle these sorts of errors as I'm sure this is a common point of confusion?

Comment: Exceptions are your way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like `Hotmail>>login(user, password)` I would definitely use exceptions. How fine grained to be with exceptions its up to you (and your domain model) and it can be hard to achieve a balance.

For this case I would definitely have exceptions for the most important events (like `WrongCredentialsException`) but I wouldn't have an exception class for every 4XX and 5XX response errors. However, according to your domain and personal tastes you could  have a `ClientException` and `ServerException`, with an instance variable stating the error number instead of just having a `ConnectionException`.

HTH